# Where can I find missed hpccinf.txt for hpcc?

Tags: performance, benchmarks

I have installed [`hpcc`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/hpcc) package to benchmark my system. Its description is as follows:

> Description-en: HPC Challenge benchmark
>    The High Performance Computing (HPC) Challenge benchmark runs a suite
>    of 7 tests that measure the performance of CPU, memory and network for
>    HPC clusters.  Amongst others, it includes the High-Performance LINPACK
>    (HPL) benchmark, used by the Top500 ranking (http://www.top500.org/).

It has executable named `hpcc` and placed in `/usr/bin/hpcc`.

If I run it - I get error message:

```
$ hpcc 
HPL WARNING from process # 0, on line 313 of function HPL_pdinfo:
>>> cannot open file hpccinf.txt <<<
```

How to correctly run `hpcc` and where can I get `hpccinf.txt` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`man hpcc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/hpcc.1.html)

> The  High  Performance  Computing  (HPC)  Challenge  benchmark  runs a suite of tests that
>          measure the performance of CPU, memory and network  for  HPC  clusters.   hpcc  takes  its
>          parameters    from    a    hpccinf.txt    file.    An    example    can    be   found   in
>          `/usr/share/doc/hpcc/examples/_hpccinf.txt`.

So we need to copy `/usr/share/doc/hpcc/examples/_hpccinf.txt` to current directory with name `hpccinf.txt`, edit it and run it with `mpirun.openmpi hpcc` as described in `/usr/share/doc/hpcc/README.Debian`:

> ### HPC Challenge Benchmark for Debian
>
> Please read `/usr/share/doc/hpcc/README.txt.gz`, especially section
>   'Runtime configuration'.
>
> An `hpccinf.txt` input file is provided as
>   `/usr/share/doc/hpcc/examples/_hpccinf.txt`. Copy it into your current
>   dir, tune it and launch `hpcc` using `mpirun.openmpi`: $ `mpirun.openmpi`
>   `hpcc`
>
> -- Lucas Nussbaum   Sat, 13 Jun 2009
>   16:04:17 +0200

So we have two options:

- use default `hpccinf.txt` from repository and run benchmark

  ```
  cp /usr/share/doc/hpcc/examples/_hpccinf.txt hpccinf.txt
  mpirun.openmpi -np $(nproc) hpcc
  ```

  The results will be saved in `hpccoutf.txt` file.
- customize `hpccinf.txt` for modern systems with 4-8 cores (solving matrix with 10000x10000 dimmensions):

  ```
  cat << EOF > hpccinf.txt
  HPLinpack benchmark input file
  Innovative Computing Laboratory, University of Tennessee
  HPL.out      output file name (if any)
  6            device out (6=stdout,7=stderr,file)
  1            # of problems sizes (N)
  10000        Ns
  1            # of NBs
  128          NBs
  0            PMAP process mapping (0=Row-,1=Column-major)
  1            # of process grids (P x Q)
  1            Ps
  1            Qs
  16.0         threshold
  1            # of panel fact
  2            PFACTs (0=left, 1=Crout, 2=Right)
  1            # of recursive stopping criterium
  4            NBMINs (>= 1)
  1            # of panels in recursion
  2            NDIVs
  1            # of recursive panel fact.
  1            RFACTs (0=left, 1=Crout, 2=Right)
  1            # of broadcast
  1            BCASTs (0=1rg,1=1rM,2=2rg,3=2rM,4=Lng,5=LnM)
  1            # of lookahead depth
  1            DEPTHs (>=0)
  0            SWAP (0=bin-exch,1=long,2=mix)
  1            swapping threshold
  1            L1 in (0=transposed,1=no-transposed) form
  1            U  in (0=transposed,1=no-transposed) form
  0            Equilibration (0=no,1=yes)
  8            memory alignment in double (> 0)
  EOF
  ```

  Then run benchmark and interpret the results

  ```
  mpirun.openmpi -np $(nproc) hpcc && grep Gflops$ -A3 hpccoutf.txt
  ```

  Examples for 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS:

  ```
  +------------------------+---------|-----------+----|----|
  |       CPU              | Threads |  Gflops   | Ps | Qs |
  +------------------------+---------+-----------|----+----+
  | Intel i7-740QM         |    8    |    16.4   |  1 |  1 |
  | Intel i7-920           |    8    |    28.1   |  2 |  2 |
  | Intel i7-4790          |    8    |   137.1   |  1 |  1 |
  | Intel i7-3537U         |    4    |    14.3   |  2 |  2 |
  | AMD A4-4000            |    2    |     6.6   |  2 |  1 |
  | Intel Core 2 Duo E8300 |    2    |    16.2   |  2 |  1 |
  | Intel Pentium G3420    |    2    |    26.1   |  2 |  1 |
  | Raspberry Pi 3B+       |    4    |     1.9   |  1 |  1 |
  +------------------------+---------+-----------|----+----+
  ```

Note: if have Intel you can use also their [optimized LINPACK benchmark](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-benchmarks-suite). Its results is +25% higher.

Comment: You also could use the generator [here](http://www.advancedclustering.com/act_kb/tune-hpl-dat-file/)